# What is the jsize type in Java Native Interface?

Tags: java, arrays, java-native-interface

**jsize** is used to get the array length as show below.

```
// Here buf is a jArray type
jsize length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, buf);
```

What is **jsize** type in JNI. How it different from **jint**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html), `jsize` is a synonym for `jint`.

```
typedef jint jsize;
```